# Replication from EC2 Master to RDS Slave - Connecting to master

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds, amazon-ec2

I am migrating my company's database from an EC2 instance to an RDS instance. I have already migrated a snapshot of data and am now trying to set up replication to get the data that has been added since the snapshot.

I am following the instructions at this link:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html

When I call `mysql.rds_start_replication` , `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` shows the following:

```
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
```

From my Googling on the subject matter, I'm led to believe this is a network/firewall problem. I've checked that my RDS has a security group allowing all network traffic with the source machine (both private IP and Elastic IP) and the source machine has a security group allowing all network traffic with the RDS instance IP address.

The master server has a user set up with replication privileges.

I'm sure there must be something easy I'm missing here.

I've tried running `flush hosts` on the master server.

How do I get the replication to proceed successfully?

**Some additional information:**

1. The master server is version 5.5.33
2. The slave server is version 5.6.13
3. The master server is using old_passwords=1
4. The slave server is using old_passwords=0

I've tried setting `SESSION old_passwords=0` on the master, creating a new replication user with a new, long hash format, but still can't get replication to start.

The error I get is:

```
        Last_IO_Errno: 2049
```

which seems to relate to the authentication protocol.

Do I need to completely restart the MySQL master server, with old_passwords=0 in the my.cnf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you control `my.cnf` on EC2, you have two options, neither of which require restarting mysql

## OPTION #1 : Change old_password Protocol for EC2

1. Stop replication to the RDS Slave
2. As root@localhost run this on EC2 : `SET GLOBAL old_passwords = 0;`
3. Start replication to the RDS Slave

## OPTION #2 : Lower the Security for EC2

1. Stop replication to the RDS Slave
2. As root@localhost run this : `SET GLOBAL secure_auth = OFF;`
3. Start replication to the RDS Slave

For more information, please read the [old_passwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_old_passwords) and [secure_auth](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_secure-auth) MySQL Documentation.

## Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2017-07-20 16:32 EDT

#### Neither of these methods work for MySQL 5.7 as both options are deprecated.

Comment: Since posting my question I've already completed the migration of the production MySQL database (using mysqlbinlog to apply updates missing since the baseline dump) but I've tried the above in a test instance and it worked - thanks!