# Configuring slave from EC2 master to Amazon RDS slave

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds, amazon-ec2

I am configuring replication from EC2 master to Amazon RDS instance.

After starting the slave, I don't see any errors but I see slave_IO:

```
_thread is connecting. 

Master version:5.6.23
Slave Version:5.6.19
```

#### show slave status \G

```
mysql> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: XXXXXXXXXXX
                  Master_User: XXXXXX
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: cli-bin.000032
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 713
               Relay_Log_File: relaylog.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: cli-bin.000032
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: mysql.plugin,innodb_memcache.cache_policies,mysql.rds_sysinfo,mysql.rds_replication_status,mysql.rds_history,innodb_memcache.config_options
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 713
              Relay_Log_Space: 618
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### show global variables

```
mysql> show global variables like '%old_passwords%';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| old_passwords | 0     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show global variables like '%secure_auth%';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| secure_auth   | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
====================
```

The problem is Slave_IO_state is connecting and Slave_io_thread is connecting state but replication is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer generated from question comments by [jynus](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30545/jynus):*</sub>

You may not have opened the right ports or provided the `REPLICATION SLAVE` permissions:

[Using Replication to Export MySQL 5.6 Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html)

Also see this answer:

[Replication from EC2 Master to RDS Slave - Connecting to master](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63056/replication-from-ec2-master-to-rds-slave-connecting-to-master)